# ImportError: No module named http_client

Tags: python, firebase

I recently tried to start working with Pyrebase and after installing Python 2.7.13 and installing Pyrebase, the module http_client is missing and therefore cannot import HTTPConnection. I tried uninstalling pyrebase and reinstalling it to see if then all the the modules would be included this time but i still get the same import error stating that the module http_client is nonexistant. Any ideas?

Here is the code:

```
import pyrebase

config = {
   "apiKey": "AIzaSyBYJ9WC68XJg6jGwAGwwxT3wcvGAti4FOg",
   "authDomain": "app-2-b1b3e.firebaseapp.com",
   "databaseURL": "https://app-2-b1b3e.firebaseio.com/",
   "storageBucket": "app-2-b1b3e.appspot.com"
}

fb = pyrebase.initialize_app(config)
firebase = fb.database()
def dataSentTest():
    data = {"name": "Mortimer 'Morty' Smith"}
    firebase.child("users").child("Morty").set(data)

dataSentTest()
```

Here is the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/sam/Desktop/Selfie Dash/DataListener.py", line 1, in        <module>
import pyrebase
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pyrebase/__init__.py", line 1,     in <module>
from .pyrebase import initialize_app
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pyrebase/pyrebase.py", line 18, in <module>
from gcloud import storage
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/gcloud/storage/__init__.py",  line 43, in <module>
from gcloud.storage.blob import Blob
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/gcloud/storage/blob.py", line 30, in <module>
from gcloud._helpers import _rfc3339_to_datetime
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/gcloud/_helpers.py", line 30, in <module>
from six.moves.http_client import HTTPConnection
ImportError: No module named http_client
[Finished in 0.5s with exit code 1]
```

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

This is pytrebase requirements.txt file

```
requests==2.11.1
gcloud==0.17.0
oauth2client==3.0.0
requests-toolbelt==0.7.0
python-jwt==2.0.1
pycrypto==2.6.1
```

I suggest you install these dependencies, command:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```